# Moveit2 Tutorial - Move Group C++ Interface. Not Avoiding the Placed Box

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial runs flawlessly with no errors or failures, however when the box is placed in the world. The robot does not seem to care that it is there and rams right into it.

Tutorial Link: http://moveit2_tutorials.picknik.ai/doc/move_group_interface/move_group_interface_tutorial.html

Has anyone else had this happen or seen this and have a solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378638/moveit2-tutorial---move-group-c++-interface.-not-avoiding-the-placed-box/) by [GusBus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26964/gusbus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2021-05-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-05-19**:
What tutorial? Can you please update your question with a link to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This PR should have fixed it. Please 'git pull' moveit2 and I think it will be fixed.

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/pull/464

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2021-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GusBus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26964/gusbus/) on 2021-05-20**:
Brilliant thanks for the update. That has fixed the problem.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-05-20**:
@GusBus if this answered your question then please click on the checkmark next to the answer to mark it as correct